# Missing values for different dependent variables

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

I did an experiment across four weeks to collect data on different dependent variables to answer diverse sub-questions. Since on each dependent variable, different participants did not show up and thus I have different missing data from different participants. 
Should I remove all different participants' data on different dependent variables? Or should I use the data I have for each dependent variable?

Comment: Generally speaking, merely deleting/ignoring incomplete records is not recommended. More details would allow more specific advice.